# What is the typographically- and semantically-correct way to typeset math intervals?

Tags: math-mode

I want to typeset a math interval like `[-2, 2]` and I would like to know the correct way to do it. Should I just use

```latex
$ \left[ -2, 2 \right] $
```

or is there a way to do it that has the semantic meaning of "closed interval"? I would like to typeset mixed intervals like `[-2, 2)` as well, so if the answer could cover that, that would be great!

I did look on this site, but the other questions seemed to be about typesetting intervals as `]-2, 2[`, which is not what I'm asking.

Comment: There is no reason to use left/right here. Normally [...) are fine, they typeset fine. Its the ]... [ which is bad and gets the wrong spacing. See also the interval package (disclaimer, I maintain it)

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/interval